# Android Button weird behavior when tapping fast on Android version 2.3.x

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

A Button strangely reacts to rapid tapping (a click is only supposed to change the text within the button) : it resizes, being larger, even if text is very small.

If I tap on it, and stays down for like half a second and then remove my finger, the minWidth attribute is respected.

I can get back to the original size by doing the "long tap", and enlarge it by doing the "short tap". Works every time.

I can't reproduce this problem on 4.0+ (but I haven't tried hard), and seems to always happen on 2.3.X devices (I tried it on HTC Desire S with 2.3.5, and Galaxy S2 with 2.3.6).

Following is the xml code related to this button :

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/header_left_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/very_small_item_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_nav_background"
    android:minWidth="70dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

And the OnClick listener :

```
mBtnTextHeaderLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
        mBtnTextHeaderLeft.setText("OK");
});
```

Any thoughts ?

**EDIT :**

The selector is defined this way :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_map_bottom_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_map_bottom_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

**EDIT 2 :**
Following are screenshots of the two states of the button (sorry I don't have enough reputation to directly add images...) :

[normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZxJm.jpg) (when button has not been tapped yet, or if I tap "slowly" on it)

[bugged size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ZLk.jpg) (when button has been tapped "quickly")

Comment: Visibility is set to Gone. It will not be visible.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the button is made visible on OnCreate(). It is visible when user taps on it.

Comment: Please also note that if I remove    `android:background="@drawable/btn_nav_background"`, which is a selector between multilple 9-patches, the button does not resize.

Comment: What are the selection state resources?

Comment: My first instinct is to say that your two drawables have different sizes. Since you have the width as `wrap_content`, the pressed drawable could be stretching it, causing a layout pass.

Comment: @Delyan The two drawables have indeed different sizes (pressed one being bigger). What I don't understand is that both 9patches are correctly set up (fill & scalable areas), therefore they should resize to match the "wrap_content" attribute. And why isn't it happening on recent phones or when I tap "slowly" ??

Comment: I've no idea why it's not happening on newer devices, a lot changed in the View system between 2.3 and 4.0. My guess is that the change in drawable size causes a remeasure/layout pass, which somehow doesn't happen if you tap more slowly. That said, there's absolutely no reason they should be different sizes. If you'd like the button to become bigger, use animations (Jake Wharton's wonderful nineoldandroids would be a good choice).

Comment: Actually, I'd like the button to keep its size when user taps on it. I'll look deeper in my 9-patches to see if I can modify them. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use lock for your case

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
mBtnTextHeaderLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
         mBtnTextHeaderLeft.setText("OK");

       } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {

                lock.unlock();
            }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Behavior is still exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot to your problem and expand the problem with specefic description.

Comment: You should verify the selector and verify the drawable 
drawable="@drawable/btn_map_bottom_normal and the other it should be have the same width and height